Script to Switch the Distributor of a Publisher
According to the documentation below, in order to change the Distribution Server for a Publisher, Publishing and Distribution must be disabled and then the Distribution reconfigured.

To change the distributor of a publisher in SQL Server, you need to
access the Publisher properties in SQL Server Management Studio,
disable publishing on the publisher, then reconfigure publishing and
distribution, selecting the new desired distributor server as the
distribution point; this can be done by navigating to the Replication
folder, right-clicking the Publisher, and choosing "Publisher
Properties" to modify the Distributor settings

If a new remote Distributor (not the publisher) has been configured to act as a Distibutor for said Publisher, then can the reconfiguration at the Publisher be done by script?
EDIT: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the Publisher in question is currently configured as its own distributor and has a number of pubs/subs running.
